# Convert a JSON value to another JSON shape?

Tags: json, ruby

I have the following JSON file that I need to transform.

Original JSON file:

```
{
  "configs": [ 
    {
      "ignore": "this",
      "key": "abc123",      
      "default": false
    },    
    {
      "ignore": "that",
      "key": "def123",    
      "default": "#F5F5F5"
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "key": "ghi123",      
      "default": "#3d4246"
    }
  ]    
}
```

I want to convert the JSON to look like this:

```
{
   "configs": [
    {
        "abc123": false
    },
    {
        "def123": "#F5F5F5"        
    },
    {
        "ghi123": "#3d4246"
    }
   ] 

}
```

How can I do this?
    require 'json'

```
original_json = JSON.parse("...") #original JSON shape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's likely a cleaner way, but here's a shot:

```
require 'json'

original_json = JSON.parse('{
  "configs": [ 
    {
      "ignore": "this",
      "key": "abc123",      
      "default": false
    },    
    {
      "ignore": "that",
      "key": "def123",    
      "default": "#F5F5F5"
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "key": "ghi123",      
      "default": "#3d4246"
    }
  ]    
}')

original_json['configs'].each do |h| 
  k = h["key"]
  v = h["default"]
  h.clear
  h[k] = v
end

original_json.to_json
#=> {"configs":[{"abc123":false},{"def123":"#F5F5F5"},{"ghi123":"#3d4246"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) you can create new hash as you want. Then you can convert it to json.

```
original_hash = JSON.parse(original_json)
new_hash = original_hash[:configs].each_with_object({ configs: [] }) do |item, new_hash|
  new_hash[:configs] << {
    item[:key] => item[:default]
    # add another key value pair if you want
  }
end

new_hash.to_json
#=>  {
#      "configs": [
#        {
#          "abc123": false
#        },
#        {
#          "def123": "#F5F5F5"
#        },
#        {
#          "ghi123": "#3d4246"
#        }
#      ]
#    }
```